# Module build failed - read only error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Trying to create a React app without using `create-react-app` so that I can learn a bit more and know what's going on in the background.

I'm trying to get webpack to work but getting this error that appears to be linked to `redux-form` when running `webpack` command.

[image]

I've just [copied code](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/GettingStarted.md/) from their site so not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Can you please provide the previous lines of the code?

Comment: They're in the link provided. I've only used the code that's on the page

Comment: It's a strict mode error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only