# React Module build failed: SyntaxError: "..." is read-only

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting this error when web pack compiles:

[image]

I couldn't find an answer on google or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44189547/3321344).
Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ContactInfo from './ContactInfo'

const CheckoutForm = props => {
    return (
              <Form className="forms" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                  <PanelGroup id="checkout-panels">
                      <ContactInfo {...props} />
                  </PanelGroup>
                  <Button className="btn-green pull-right" type="submit" >Submit</Button>
              </Form>
    )
}

CheckoutForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'checkoutForm',
    destroyOnUnmount: true
})(CheckoutForm)

CheckoutForm = connect(state => ({
    initialValues: 
        { 
            payment_type: 'credit_card', 
            ...state.checkout 
        }
}))(CheckoutForm)

export default CheckoutForm
```

Can anyone help? I'm sure its a super simple fix. I just can't find it. Thank you!

Comment: Why the down vote? I genuinely think this question contains enough detail and would help someone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
const CheckoutForm
```

Change it for

```
let CheckoutForm
```

Consts are read-only, you just can set a value one time, and after that you can't change it.

Read here about consts [Const in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found it. It was a simple oversight. Hope this helps someone.

I needed to change `const` to `let`:

```
let CheckoutForm = props => {
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```